# How to get name of the control item on which contextmenu was executed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, contextmenu

I have several textblocks functioning as tiles. What I want to do is to tap and hold on any of the textblocks and get a contextmenu. This I have done and this works fine. Where I am stuck is when I tap on a menuitem inside the contextmenu, I want to know on which textblock the menuitem was tapped. How can I achieve that?

I have already tried something like this but without luck:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
        var sndr = menuItem.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem((sender as ContextMenu).DataContext).ToString();
        // var sndr = menuItem.DataContext.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("you tapped at " + sndr);
    }
```

This is the xaml code where the contextmenu and tetblocks are located:

```
 <ScrollViewer>
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="holdOptions">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="New" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Clear" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <Grid> 
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="208" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="208" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="210"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="210" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="210" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Height="205" Width="205">
                        <TextBlock Height="205" Width="205" Name="con1" Text="Tap to add" Tap="con1_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" Hold="con1_Hold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Height="205" Width="205">
                        <TextBlock Height="205" Width="205" Name="con2" Text="Tap to add" Tap="con2_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" Hold="con2_Hold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Height="205" Width="205">
                        <TextBlock Height="205" Width="205" Name="con3" Text="Tap to add" Tap="con3_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" Hold="con3_Hold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Height="205" Width="205">
                        <TextBlock Height="205" Width="205" Name="con4" Text="Tap to add" Tap="con4_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" Hold="con4_Hold" />
                    </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found that works is to attach a separate context menu to each TextBlock.

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Height="205" Width="205">
        <TextBlock Height="205" Width="205" Name="con1" Text="Tap to add" Tap="con1_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" Hold="con1_Hold"/>
          <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="holdOptions">
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="New" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Clear" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Height="205" Width="205">
        <TextBlock Height="205" Width="205" Name="con2" Text="Tap to add" Tap="con2_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" Hold="con2_Hold" >
          <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="holdOptions">
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="New" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Clear" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
```

Then you can just use

```
var menuItem = ((MenuItem)sender);
```

It's far from ideal but as long as you don't have too many items that you want to attach the context menu to its not too bad, although if anyone has a better solution I'd like to know it too.